# Difference between git add ., git add -A and git add -u

Tags: git, version-control, git-add

What is the difference between the following commands?

- git add .
- git add -A
- git add -u

I tried to execute them, and they create the same results.

Comment: Couldn't find that duplicate before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git help add`

```
   -A, --all, --no-ignore-removal
       Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching <pathspec> but also where the index already has an
       entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.

       If no <pathspec> is given, the current version of Git defaults to "."; in other words, update all files in the current
       directory and its subdirectories. This default will change in a future version of Git, hence the form without <pathspec>
       should not be used.

   -u, --update
       Update the index just where it already has an entry matching <pathspec>. This removes as well as modifies index entries to
       match the working tree, but adds no new files.

       If no <pathspec> is given, the current version of Git defaults to "."; in other words, update all tracked files in the
       current directory and its subdirectories. This default will change in a future version of Git, hence the form without
       <pathspec> should not be used.
```

- `.` is implied by both `-A` and `-u` if no `<pathspec>` is given (which is the case in your question).
- `-A` will stage changes, removed files, and added files.
- `-u` will stage changes and removed files, but *not* added files.

Comment: Isn't there a difference between Git 2.0 and earlier versions, Git 1.X?